# Deleted all Rails Migrations and dropped the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I have a rails 5 app with PostgreSQL as database, and I for some reason have dropped the database and also deleted all the migration files in db/migrate folder. Is there any way to generate a single migration file based on models and views without generating individual migration files specifying the columns to rebuild the database?

Comment: In addition to Slomojo's answer you should always check your project into Git.

Answer (score 6):

If you have the `db/schema.rb` you can setup the database from there.

```
rails db:schema:load
```

Will setup the database from the schema.

It is also relatively simple to convert the `schema.rb` to an initial setup migration, effectively you copy everything that's inside `ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: timestamp) do` block

Then paste it into a new migration inside a `def up ... end` method.

This is also the exact time to get your project into `git` version control and avoid nightmare situations like this again.